# Tesseract in Intellij cannot read pdf because 'gsdll64' library is unable to load

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tesseract

I am attempting to read a pdf with the Tesseract OCR reader. It works for image files quite well though.

Here is what I have done:

1. Create a Maven Project.
2. Added tess4j version **4.4.1** as a dependency.
3. Changed java version to **13**.
4. Added the following code:

   ```
   import net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract;

   import java.io.File;

   public class OcrReader {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
       String inputFilePath = "C:\\Users\\non\\Desktop\\1.pdf";

       Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
       tesseract.setDatapath("C:\\Users\\non\\Desktop\\tessdata\\");
     //tesseract.setLanguage("dan");
       String string = tesseract.doOCR(new File(inputFilePath));
       System.out.println(string);
   }
   }
   ```

I get the following error afterwards:

```
10:40:46.208 [main] ERROR net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.PdfGsUtilities - Unable to load library 'gsdll64':
The specified module could not be found.

The specified module could not be found.

The specified module could not be found.

Native library (win32-x86-64/gsdll64.dll) not found in resource path (C:\Users\non\IdeaProjects\OcrSample\target\classes;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\tess4j\tess4j\4.4.1\tess4j-4.4.1.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna\5.4.0\jna-5.4.0.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\com\github\jai-imageio\jai-imageio-core\1.4.0\jai-imageio-core-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\org\ghost4j\ghost4j\1.0.1\ghost4j-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.9.2\commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\xmlgraphics-commons\1.4\xmlgraphics-commons-1.4.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\com\lowagie\itext\2.1.7\itext-2.1.7.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\pdfbox\2.0.17\pdfbox-2.0.17.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\fontbox\2.0.17\fontbox-2.0.17.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\pdfbox-tools\2.0.17\pdfbox-tools-2.0.17.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\pdfbox-debugger\2.0.17\pdfbox-debugger-2.0.17.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\org\apache\pdfbox\jbig2-imageio\3.0.2\jbig2-imageio-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.6\commons-io-2.6.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\lept4j\lept4j\1.12.3\lept4j-1.12.3.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jboss-vfs\3.2.14.Final\jboss-vfs-3.2.14.Final.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.1.4.GA\jboss-logging-3.1.4.GA.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.28\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.28.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.28\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.28.jar;C:\Users\non\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\log4j-over-slf4j\1.7.28\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.28.jar)

10:40:46.849 [main] DEBUG org.apache.fontbox.ttf.PostScriptTable - No PostScript name information is provided for the font Cambria
```

**How do I go about solving this?**

Comment: Do you have Ghostscript installed at all?

Comment: unrelated to this - PDFBox is at 2.0.19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you install Ghostscript correctly?

It should include a file gsdll32.dll.

If not, download **the Ghostscript installer for Win64** from this link https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html and run it.

After the installation, there should be a file gsdll64.dll in the directory

%your_install_dir%\gs\gs9.05\bin\

I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: I have downloaded it and I can find the location as you have written. But the error still persists.Should I do something in Intellij after installing it?

Comment: you just need to copy the dlls with the directory in the location of the src package.